# Concatenating strings with newlines in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I am unable to concatenate strings having new lines in tcl. The new lines are ignored. Is there a way to overcome this?

```
% set pst_data "Power states :-\n"
Power states :-

% set pst_data [concat $pst_data "vcc1\t 1 0 1\n"]
Power states :- vcc1     1 0 1
% set pst_data [concat $pst_data "vcc2\t 2 2 0\n"]
Power states :- vcc1     1 0 1 vcc2      2 2 0
%
```

I want the output to come in separate new lines every time

Comment: While `append` is the command _designed for building strings like this by pieces,_ `string cat` is also available in 8.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It mentions it in the [manual](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/concat.htm):

> This command joins each of its arguments together with spaces **after trimming leading and trailing white-space from each of them**.

You could try using [`append`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/append.htm) instead:

```
% set pst_data "Power states :-\n"
Power states :-

% append pst_data "vcc1\t 1 0 1\n"
Power states :-
vcc1     1 0 1

% append pst_data "vcc1\t 1 0 1\n"
Power states :-
vcc1     1 0 1
vcc1     1 0 1

%
```

Comment: Can also do `append pst_data "vcc1\t 1 0 1" "\n"` so that the newline is separate. This is especially useful when the rest of the string is coming from a variable.

Comment: The manual also starts with "concat - join lists together", which should be a hint if you don't have lists, but rather strings.

Answer (score 0):

Of course append is the correct way to accomplish this, but in Tcl you could even do the concat like this:

```
% set pst_data "Power states :-\n"
Power states :-

% set pst_data "${pst_data}vcc1\t 1 0 1\n"
Power states :-
vcc1     1 0 1
```

Comment: There's not only the string type in Tcl, that's like saying that there's only ones and zeros in all programming languaged. Tcl is just not typed, so you can send a list instead of a floating point number to a procedure, but that doesn't mean that you should do it